# dynamic itemdata values in loadrunner

Tags: loadrunner

How can i build a dynamic/variable set of ITEMDATA values in a POST statement like the below

```
web_submit_data("Save", 
    "Action={SSL}://{host}/xxxxxxxxx/Save/22?xxxxxxx=False ", 
    "Method=POST", 
    "RecContentType=text/html", 
    ::::::::
    ITEMDATA, 
    "Name= SaveDTO", "Value=", ENDITEM,         
    "Name= Roles[1].MemId ", "Value={MemId_1}", ENDITEM, 
    "Name= Roles[1].EmpId", "Value={EmpId_1}", ENDITEM, 
    "Name= Roles[2].MemId ", "Value={MemId_2}", ENDITEM,
    :::::
```

Thanks,
N

Answer (score 1):

You use web_custom_request() to dynamically build the name|value pair data for your request.

Save a copy of your script to a new name.   Regenerate the second script as web_custom_requests() only.  Look for your label tag of  "save" and you should find your web_custom_request() for the request in question.

You would then leverage your tool mechanical skills in correlation to collect all of the name|value pair data from any previous requests and pair them with your foundation skills in C to dynamically build the string that you need to populate the web_custom_request().